# MariaDB PCRE gives ERROR 1644. What am I missing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

First, the version I am using:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

The following all works fine except for the final statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1; USE db1;
CREATE TABLE tb1 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    word VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tb1 (word) VALUES ('foo');
DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE word='foo';
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_word_insert BEFORE INSERT ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.word=TRIM(NEW.word);
        IF (NEW.word REGEXP "^\w+$" = 0) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid word';
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
INSERT INTO tb1 (word) VALUES ('foo');
```

which results in:

```
ERROR 1644 (12345): Invalid word
```

This is baffling, because the Perl-compatible Regular Expression `\w+` surely ought to match the string `foo`. As such, I would have expected that final SQL statement to have been executed without an error.

So, what *is* causing the error?

Comment: What api is being used to feed this `CREATE` to the server?  Is it something that will consume the backslash, or not?

Comment: @RickJames, just the `mysql` CLI utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is simply that you don't escape the backslash or use SQL mode as described [Here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/#pcre-syntax)

> Note, the backslash characters (here, and in all examples in the
>   sections below) must be escaped with another backslash, unless you're
>   using the SQL_MODE NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES.
>
> This example tests if a character has hex code 0x61:
>   `SELECT 'a' RLIKE '\\x{61}';`

Your current code would evaluate to 1 against the litteral string '\w'

Comment: Absolutely correct, and I just spotted that the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/) even give an example very much like mine: `SELECT 'abc' RLIKE '^\\w+$';`. Why I forgot about having to quote the backslashes in MariaDB (unlike in e.g. Python, etc), I don't know. But I did completely forget. Hopefully, having asked this on SO, it'll help out the next person who forgets, too :)

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, the key passage from the docs is this: **"Note, the backslash characters ... must be escaped with another backslash, unless you're using the [SQL_MODE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-mode/) `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`."**

Answer (score 1):

You should be using single quotes.  So you have written this:

```
NEW.word REGEXP '^\w+$' = 0
```

It is being parsed as:

```
(NEW.word REGEXP '^\w+$') = 0
```

I think this is the cause of your error.  Because when the regular expression matches, then the parenthesized part returns "1", which fails the test.  When it doesn't match, it returns "0", which passes the test.  The `= 0` effectively is a `NOT`.

(Note:  `=` for comparison and `REGEXP` have the same precedence according to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/operator-precedence/).)

You don't want or need an `=`:

```
NEW.word REGEXP '^\w+$'
```

Comment: If you meant that my line `IF (NEW.word REGEXP "^\w+$" = 0) THEN` would have been better written as `IF NOT (NEW.word REGEXP '^\\w+$') THEN`, I agree with you. Upvoted your answer accordingly. Thanks for the tip. It does, however, appear to still need the double backslash, as per Cyril Lemaire's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not all regexp things work.  Switch to this (with either `'` or `"`).

```
REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$'
```

(This answer works in MariaDB, Percona, and Oracle's MySQL).

Comment: `\w` does work. It just needs to have its backslash escaped with another backslash. Your suggestion would also work, but `[[:alnum:]]` is quite a bit more verbose than `\\w`.